# Java FX Glow Effect in CSS

Tags: css, javafx, effects

I am working with Java 8, I know that Java FX possesses two types of this effect Glow and Bloom. I also know how to apply these effects in code.

However, I'd like to apply these effects in CSS in the same way I can apply an **innershaddow** or **dropshaddow** like below:

```
.some-style Text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.5) , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}
```

However looking at the [CSS reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) I could only see **dropshaddow** and **innershaddow** listed. I've had a stab at attempting to use Glow and Bloom in CSS but the parser told me the function was unexpected. Can the glow or bloom effect not be applied via CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the glow or bloom effect not be applied via CSS?

No. CSS support for these effects is not part of the Java 8 feature set.

There is an existing feature request to add CSS support for more effects to future Java versions:

- [JDK-8090342 Add CSS support for more effects (additional to innershadow and dropshadow)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090342)